# In Atlassain Bamboo, how do I point my script to read files from Stash Repo?

Tags: bitbucket, bamboo

I have a couple of files in Stash Repo, and I need to compare them and generate a delta file. I am using Atlassain Bamboo tool to do this task.

There is a Script utility Under Task, how do I point my script to read files from Stash Repo?

Answer (score 2):

In script task you can run `git clone` command to fetch files from Stash repo.  Or you can use Checkout task to fetch files from repository

Comment: `Checkout task` I think is the better way to do it.  @st_bones you should accept this answer.